# How do I use/enable Tor when using Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, privacy

I live in a country that blocks most types Internet access and protocols so I need to utilize Tor from the command line. I haven't come across much useful information in this regard, so any information would be helpful.

I've already downloaded the Tor/Vidalia bundle, although it appears to only work through the provided web-browser that it utilizes. That is great for searching the web, etc. but I need to `ssh` and use `curl`, etc., too.

Answer (score 2):

Running Tor provides a standard proxy you can connect to at localhost:9050 with anything that supports the SOCKS protocol. Just search online for something like "SSH over Tor", or if that fails, "SSH through SOCKS proxy".

Two examples:

- [SSH](http://www.justinbull.ca/blog/ssh-over-tor-on-mac-os-x):

  ssh -o ProxyCommand="nc -X 4 -x localhost:9050 %h %p" example.com
- curl:

  curl --socks4a localhost:9050 example.com

Comment: hi, would you have an example of using a perl script as well? i need to use it like: `perl script.pl -scriptargs -moreargs -args`

Comment: It depends on the script. It would have to be written to work with a SOCKS proxy.